# How to set the font of a ToolTip same as parent control in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip

I have a number of fields where different fonts are used. When I hover the mouse over a field, it's always showing the ToolTip with a default font.
But I want to set the ToolTip font same as the field over which I'm hovering my mouse.
How can I do this?

Here is the style of the ToolTip:

```
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               MaxWidth="400"
                               TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here is the XAML of the main content:

```
    <TextBox Text="Hello there!"
             FontFamily="Cambria"
             ToolTip="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is working and `generic`:

```
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.FontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           MaxWidth="400"
                           TextWrapping='Wrap' />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

#### Preview

[image: Preview]

Comment: Can I use a generic AncestorType here? Cause I have different types of field (Date, TextBlock etc...)

Answer (score 4):

ToolTip has `PlacementTarget` property (The UIElement that is the logical parent of the ToolTip control (TextBox, TextBlock, whatever)). Create FontFamily binding to PlacementTarget.FontFamily

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}, Path=PlacementTarget.FontFamily}"
                       MaxWidth="400"
                       TextWrapping='Wrap' />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Why AncestorType=ToolTip?
And unfortunately, this solution is not working in my case :(

Comment: @AliAkber, `AncestorType=ToolTip` is required because 1. that is ContentTemplate for ToolTip. 2. ToolTip has PlacementTarget property. I tested this with TextBox example from the question in a new window. Which case doesn't work?

Comment: It isn't working in any of the cases. If I change the RelativeSource to Self then it works.

Comment: @AliAkber, hm, it works indeed but only if I use style setter `<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.FontFamily}"/>`. just go on with your working solution

Comment: Yes you are right. I was setting the FontFamily as setter. Now that I added FontFamily inside the TextBlock, it worked. As Dominic answered first, I'm marking his answer as accepted. I'm giving you +1 for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code but it will work only for `TextBox`.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
        MaxWidth="400"
        FontFamily="{Binding FontFamily, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}"
        TextWrapping='Wrap' />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Can I use a generic AncestorType here? Cause I have different types of field (Date, TextBlock etc...)

Comment: I think you can't but you can define different style resources for each type of parent and set specific style using `StaticResource` key. It would also be better if you set `FontFamily` resource and reference it for both `TextBlock` and `ToolTip`. It's also useful for any other controls.